# Confused on int conversion

Tags: json, node.js, parseint

I'm writing a node js program that does the below.

1. get the json.
2. parse it.
3. print to console.

Currently I'm able to do the above three things very smoothly. But my problem comes up here. I'm trying to convert a value from json to `int`. and below is my sample data.

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "accountId": "12345",
            "pin": "1234",
            "userId": "user1",
            "dueDate": "5/20/2017",
            "_id": "2",
            "dueAmount": "4000",
            "totalBalance": "10000"
        }
    ],
    "Count": 1,
    "ScannedCount": 4
}
```

and from the above json I'll need the `dueAmount` in int format so I tried the below code.

```
var userDueDate = JSON.stringify(res.Items[0].dueDate);
var userDueAmount = JSON.stringify(res.Items[0].dueAmount);
var userTotalBalance = JSON.stringify(res.Items[0].totalBalance);
var intUsingNumber = Number(userDueAmount);
var intUsingParseInt = parseInt(userDueAmount);
console.log('by using Number : ' + intUsingNumber + ' and the type is :' + (typeof intUsingNumber));
console.log('by using Parse : ' + intUsingParseInt + ' and the type is :' + (typeof intUsingParseInt));
```

and when I run this program I get the output as

```
by using Number : NaN and the type is :number
by using Parse : NaN and the type is :number
```

Where in I need to print `4000` instead of `NaN`.

Also, what I'm confused is, the `type` is showing it as a `number`, but the value is given as `NaN`.

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Thanks

Comment: why do you use `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @Maximus, so you mean that I can directly use `Number(res.Items[0].dueAmount)`?, I'm sorry, I'm learning node. Not much aware of these concepts.

Comment: JSON is a JS object wrapped as a string: `let json = "{"dueAmount":"4000"}"` - is a JSON object, `let jsObj =
 {"dueAmount":"4000"}` is not. If you receive a JSON object, you need to convert it to JS object by `let result = JSON.parse(json)` and then `parseInt(result.dueAmount)`

Comment: @Maximus, thanks, Now I understood how this thing works. Thanks again :)

Comment: you're welcome, I [posted it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43975330/2545680)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is a JS object wrapped as a string:

`let json = "{"dueAmount":"4000"}"` - is a JSON object, 
`let jsObj = {"dueAmount":"4000"}` is not.

If you receive a JSON object, you need to convert it to JS object by

```
let result = JSON.parse(json)
```

and then

```
parseInt(result.dueAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code** (Don't need to use JSON.stringify)

```
    var userDueDate =res.Items[0].dueDate;
    var userDueAmount = res.Items[0].dueAmount;
    var userTotalBalance = res.Items[0].totalBalance;
    var intUsingParseInt = parseInt(userDueAmount);

    console.log('by using Parse : ' + intUsingParseInt + ' and the type is :' + (typeof intUsingParseInt));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ***res*** is a JSON object. You can simply use parseInt function to get number format.

```
var am = parseInt(res.Items[0].dueAmount)
```

You should not use JSON.stringify here. Cause it converts a JSON object to a String.